# editor is not able to create instant article in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-instant-articles

I am creating a code to create instant articles on facebook using PHP SDK. I have created a login using it, and added 'public_profile,email,manage_pages,pages_show_list,pages_manage_instant_articles' permissions.

When user click on login button, it is asking for all these permissions. If user is an admin of a page and he logs in using it, he is able to create instant article on that page. But when user having an editor role of that page, tries to login, he is being asked for all these permissions, and even if he allows for all these permissions, still he is not able to create an instant article. In error log, there is a error like below:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthorizationException: (#200) Requires extended permission: pages_manage_instant_articles in ../facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/Facebook/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php:120

At first time of login, editor user was asked for all permissions and he approved all, but still this error occurred. Now when he tries to again login, he is not being asked for permissions. I have checked permissions for editor role user though "/me/permissions" endpoint. In response, "email, user_friends, pages_show_list, and public_profile" permissions have status "granted", but there is no any detail about "manage_pages and pages_manage_instant_articles" permissions.

For admin role users, all code is working fine and instant article also created using PHP SDK, but this issue comes only for editor role user.

Here is code which I have tried, I have not included my app-id, app-secret, page-id and article-html here:

```
   <?php
   session_start();
   $page_id = '{page-id}';
   $app_id='{app-id}';
   $app_secret='{app-secret}';

   require_once 'testing/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

   if(!isset($_GET['user'])){
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);

    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      //testAPI();
      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        console.log('access token -: '+accessToken);
        location.href="instant_article.php?user=logged_in";
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : <?= $app_id ?>,
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.6' // use graph api version 2.5
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,manage_pages,pages_show_list,pages_manage_instant_articles" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}else{
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => $app_id,
      'app_secret' => $app_secret,
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
      'default_access_token' => $app_id.'|'.$app_secret
    ]);
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();

    $sr = $helper->getSignedRequest();

    $user_id = $sr ? $sr->getUserId() : null;

    if ( $user_id ) {
        try {
            // Get the access token
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
            $_SESSION['user_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        } catch( Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e ) {
            // There was an error communicating with Graph
            echo "SDK error: ".$e->getMessage();
            unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
        }

        if (! isset($accessToken)) {
            echo 'No cookie set or no OAuth data could be obtained from cookie.';
            unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
        }else{
            if($accessToken->isExpired()){
                unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
                echo "<script>location.href='instant_article.php'</script>";
                exit;
            }
        }

        if(!isset($_SESSION['user_token'])){
            echo "<script>location.href='instant_article.php'</script>";
            exit;
        }

        try {
            // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
            $userToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
            $long_token = $userToken->getValue();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // There was an error communicating with Graph
            echo 'SDK error: '.$e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        /*$res_perms = $fb->get('/me/permissions?access_token='.$long_token,$long_token,'','v2.6');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($res_perms);
        exit;*/
        $res_page = $fb->get('/'.$page_id.'?fields=access_token',$long_token,'','v2.6');
        $page_info = $res_page->getDecodedBody();
        $page_token = $page_info['access_token'];

        $article_html = '{ html of article goes here}';

        if(trim($article_html) != ""){
            $page_params = array(
                'access_token'=>$page_token,
                'html_source'=>$article_html,
                'development_mode'=>true
            );
            $res_article = $fb->post('/'.$page_id.'/instant_articles',$page_params,$page_token);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

It would be great if anyone can help me for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @Daenarys , I have added my code in question.